# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data on React app

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, express

I have a React app that uses express in the backend. I try to get from my db a list of messages through a fetch API call.

The code in the Frontend:

**App.js**

```
getMessages = () => {
fetch('/api/mess')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => {
  var Messages = res.map(r => r.messages);
  this.setState({ Messages });
});
```

};

The code in the backend:

**api/mess.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var Mess = require('../queries/mess');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
        Mess.retrieveAll((err, messages) => {
        if (err)
            return res.json(err);
        return res.json(messages);
    })
});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    var message = req.body.message;
    Mess.insert(message, (err, result) => {
        if (err)
            return res.json(err);
        return res.json(result);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**queries/mess.js**

```
const db = require('../database');

class Mess {
    static retrieveAll(callback) {
        db.query('SELECT * FROM mess;', (err, res) => {
            if (err.error) 
                return callback(err);
            callback(res); 
        });
    }

    static insert(mess, callback) {
        db.query('INSERT INTO mess (messages) VALUES ($1)', [mess], (err, res) => {
            if (err.error)
                return callback(err);
            callback(res);
        });
    }
}

module.exports = Mess;
```

**index.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var db = require('./database');

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3011;

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api/mess', require('./api/mess'));
app.use('/api/roles', require('./api/roles'));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}...`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

I get this error on my Frontend:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

I have tried and changed every response and request to use either JSON.parse or .json and I get the same message no matter what.

When I use my browser and go to the api channel I get a correctly formatted JSON with the contents of the db.

[image: api]

Did I miss something?

*EDIT:*

The stack trace is super minimal: 
[image]

When I try:

`getMessages = () => {
    fetch('/api/mess')
    .then(res => console.log(res));
  };`

I get this object:

[image]

Comment: try JSON.parse(data);

Comment: The stuff in the console looks good to go - I'm guessing it's already being parsed to JSON internally, or somewhere along the way.. when you try JSON.parse on a already parsed valid object you'll get that error - try logging it without calling .json or anything on it.  I'm going to guess try taking out where you're trying to parse it on the FE : '.then(res => res.json())'

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: When I remove that line, the res.map(r => r.messages) function gives me Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): res.map is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the backend is at **PORT 3011** and the api call is made to **PORT 3000** from the frontend.

I need to have a proxy to point from the forntend to the backend port.

I need to add inside `client/package.json` *(Frontend)* this line:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost/3011"
```